# Create "archives by year and week" by category template

Tags: query-posts, archives

I'm trying to figure out a problem quite tuff;

I explain myself;

I have my pages ( which are in fact a category template).

I take for example this website: http://www.irishpost.co.uk/

Where the slider display the latest post tagged by a specific work ( coming with a theme feature); the categories of the "main container' the last post; the sidebar the most popular / viewed / shared post ( those using widget plugins).

I'd like to achieve a archive pages, by year, month and also by week depend of the year ( example: use the same design / template feature and widgets; but displaying only the post of the year 2013; another  of the month of january of the year 2013; another of the week 1 of january 2013).

Those should be display by another menu. I managed at the moment to create a new template page; where i've add a new dynamic menu; and basically copy/paste the code from the category page template to this new template.

The widget ( of for eg this website: which display:  In Sport post; In entertainment post and the Carousel popular post of the main container) display in the sidebar instead of the "main container below the slider"); and of course; does not display for the year / month / week I need. How can I link that together ?

I'm kind of confuse in the process to realise that; if anybody has nay highlight for this and the process i should use to develop that, it will be amazing !! I'm not asking for code, i ll try my best for that part. but really the process to do this ;).

Answer (score 0):

Your English isn't clear to me. What I understood is that you want to list archives of posts with specifications. Like, posts from the first week January, year 2013.

Well, there is a dedicated function for this purpose and it's: wp_get_archives();

For example, if you want posts of the first week of January, year 2013:

```
$args = array(
'type' => 'daily',
'echo' => 0,
'year' => '2013',
'month' => '1'
);
echo '<ul>'.wp_get_archives($args).'</ul>';
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, Does this array and functions will keep the widget working this way ? As in going to create page call '2013' 'january' 'week 1' etc, making them parents how can be the process do you think to link them with this functionality ? 

It should be like, clicking on the menu '2013' displaying the same design process with 2013 post.

If I click to January of the dropdown from 2013, display the same design process for the post of January 1013,

Same thing for week 1,2,3,4,

Apologies about my English I hope this is more clear.

Thank you for all your time